# how to set debug mode compile and run project one line by one line from the program entry

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I get a large Intellij Idea project about java and scala and I want to read its code in debug mode.
So I try to find the whole project entry by compiling and runing it one line by one line.
But I only found the f7 and f8, which can compile and run it by per function and per line. 
 So I am wondering **how to set debug mode and compile and run project form the begining of project** like Visual Studio.
Thanks in advances.

Comment: Scala/Java program should have only one entry point, so you can set the breakpoint somewhere inside this entry point function. So, "Step over" through it and "Step into" once you need to check a function. Doesn't that work?

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov I find the program entry by the file name. And this project will call Hadoop and Spark environment to do more pseudo-distributed computations. It is hard for me to set some breakpoints to find the program entry function in this way.